# Android Load Html response with Unicode Charecter \u000a in webview

Tags: android, html, unicode, webview

I am getting the response from webservice call like this

```
"\u000a<html>\u000a<head>\u000a<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"CACHE-CONTROL\" CONTENT=\"NO-CACHE\"\/>\u000a<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\u000a<title>Reliance<\/title>\u000a<\/head>\u000a<body>\u000a<center><img src=\"\/API\/jsp\/common\/rel\/images\/Image.png\" \/><\/center>\u000a<div align=\"center\" font:size=\"15\">\u000a<br>Invalid Request<\/div>\u000a<\/body>\u000a<\/html>\u000a"
```

How to show this response as a readble format in Android web view.

Comment: i think you have to convert it into UTF-8 format... Bt am not sure..

Comment: Please Post the full code to load html data to web view So May be help you].

Comment: Are those the actual bytes you get, or is this some string representation you're seeing in the log? FYI `"\u000a"` is a line feed.

Comment: I was adding addHeader("Accept", "application/json") to the request, so I was getting the response like that. Now I have removed the header and getting proper html response.